# A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread warning on regular Parse functions

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ios8, ios8.1

First of all, I *know* what this means. The problem is that I'm getting this error on standard calls that can't be converted to background calls. I'm getting this error on app start at:

`[Parse enableLocalDatastore];`

`PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];`

I've found out that these methods are causing the trouble by setting a symbolic breakpoint on `warnParseOperationOnMainThread` and examining the call stack.

I can't replace these calls with async ones, and as far as I know, these methods *are* meant to be called regularly from the main thread. Is this a Parse bug, or should I call all these methods from a background thread?

Comment: Have you tried setting a symbolic breakpoint where the log states? Alternative implementation is suggested when the breakpoint fires.

Comment: @soulshined of course I did, its how I found out which calls are causing the log. No, nothing is suggested other than setting the brealpoint.

Comment: Interesting to see being downvoted with no reason at all. People are really interesting these days...

Comment: Did you use any Cache Policy's methods? Disable it!

Comment: @TonyMkenu I *used to*. They result in immediate crash of the app anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to set a symbolic breakpoint .. but on `warnParseOperationOnMainThread` .. like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20989198/1702413  ??

Comment: @TonyMkenu yes, see my comments above. (I'm also updating the question to reflect that)

Comment: for PFInstallation you can use: `currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock`; PFAnalytics `cache` the request and I think here is the Parse bug.. https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFAnalytics.html

Comment: @TonyMkenu you are right about the analytics part, but getting current installation should be local. Even the Parse's own documentation clearly says it: "Gets the currently-running installation from disk and returns an instance of it.
If this installation is not stored on disk, returns a `PFInstallation` with <deviceType> and <installationId> fields set to those of the current installation."

Comment: Did you post this on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers)?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu you should do that. The Parse guys monitor that discussion forum (moreso than here at SO.)

Comment: I see the same issue

Comment: @PaulSchmitt could you post this as an answer so I can accept it for future visitors, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap the calls in...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            // any UI updates need to happen in here back on the main thread
        });
})
```

and you will no longer see the warnings.

Comment: I experience the same thing but without the PFInstallation line. Only the enableLocalDatastore line was causing the warning. Also using dispatch_async does not work, because if I do this in AppDelegate and I want to call [PFUser currentUser] the app will crash if I don't have enableLocalDatastore before [PFUser currentUser]. I can't put both in dispatch_async because I want to show a different view controller in AppDelegate depending on if PFUser currentUser exists or not, and sort of assuming that I can't really do that in dispatch_async in AppDelegate.

Comment: @Fraggie -- see the modified answer using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){});