# Standard Parse.com setup gives warning "A long-running operation is being executed..."

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

Standard Parse.com setup directly from docs, gives warning **"Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. "** Anybody else getting this?

Seems to be due to: `[Parse enableLocalDatastore];`

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

      [Parse enableLocalDatastore];

        // Initialize Parse.
        [Parse setApplicationId:@"APP_ID"
                      clientKey:@"CLIENT_ID"];

        // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];

    return YES;
    }
```

Now I could run this code using dispatch_async, I guess, except if I want to make a decision at startup based on whether the user is logged in or not. `[PFUser *user=[PFUser currentUser];` completely crashes if I don't have `[Parse enableLocalDatastore]`; first. So maybe that is another bug or something.

How can their be this many problems doing the most basic things in Parse?

Comment: Where in your code are you using currentUser?  Also are you checking if currentUser == nil before performing additional calls to the PFUser object?  If it's nil you know the user isn't logged in yet.

Comment: I don't think the issue's coming from that line. Are you performing any Parse operations as soon as your first view loads?

Comment: @MichaelGrassman well the PFUser code I left out because that is probably a separate bug, that I discovered when commenting out the enableLocalDatastore line above. Basically if you call [PFUser currentUser] after the [PFAnalytics line, it causes the app to crash if you comment out the enableLocalDatastore line.

Comment: The warning disappears if I comment out enableLocalDatastore. I got the warning with the posted code as the ONLY parse code in the app. Straight from the documentation.https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

Comment: Also this documentation leaves out 2 required frameworks which will cause the app not to build if done as they suggest: https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

Comment: Other people have experienced this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27462222/2274694

Comment: Are you using the latest release 1.6.1. It looks like they address this issue.

Comment: @MichaelGrassman yes I'm using 1.6.1

Comment: @Fraggle Were you able to figure out a way around this?

Comment: @Fraggle were you able to figure this out? If so please answer the question

Comment: No I haven't found a solution yet. Just leaving it as is for the moment, the warning doesn't seem to cause a problem at the moment, but still in early development stages for this app so hopefully it won't cause a problem down the road.

Answer (score 0):

The same bug reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1537241009878763/
It will be fixed in the next Parse SDK release.