# PFUser.loginWithUserInBackground works on simulator but not on ios device

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parse-platform

I have the following login function that on the simulator logs me in and runs the callback, but doesn't run the callback on my ipad mini iOS 8.1.2. 
On my ipad the activityIndicator just keeps spinning for eternity.

I attached the iphone 4, iOS 8.1.2, and appear to already be logged in there. This shows the login function was working some 3 to 4 weeks ago when i was testing with that.

What is the problem here?

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {

    var errorMessage = self.validateForm()
    if !errorMessage.isEmpty {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "", message: errorMessage, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
        return
    }

    self.activityIndicator.hidden=false
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    NSLog("Logging in ...")
    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(emailAddressTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text){
        (user:PFUser!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.activityIndicator.hidden=true

        if error == nil {
            if (user != nil){
            NSLog("login successful with: \(user)")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            }
        } else if error != nil {

            NSLog("login failed")
            var messageForUser = "Please try again"
            if error.code == 101 {
                messageForUser = "Please check your email address and password"
            } else if error.code == 100 {
                messageForUser = "Please check your internet connection"
            }

            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Problem logging in", message: messageForUser, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }
    }
}
```

The app is a tabbar app. I press a button to take me to a separate loginviewcontroller. When the tabbarcontroller first loads this is the stack trace:

```
2015-01-21 16:07:22.059 Tya[1610:323782] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2015-01-21 16:07:22.465 Tya[1610:323782] NewDeliveryVC loaded
2015-01-21 16:07:22.468 Tya[1610:323782] Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.
2015-01-21 16:07:22.536 Tya[1610:323782] - Current user is nil.
2015-01-21 16:07:22.537 Tya[1610:323782] - currentInput: 0
2015-01-21 16:07:22.600 Tya[1610:323782] Not logged-in
```

Then when i get to the loginviewcontroller:

```
2015-01-21 16:13:19.564 Tya[1610:323782] login Button tapped
2015-01-21 16:13:19.639 Tya[1610:323782] viewDidLoad: LoginVC.
2015-01-21 16:13:19.681 Tya[1610:323782] viewWillAppear: LoginVC
```

Comment: Does the user exist in the database?

Comment: yes i'm logging in with an existing user.

Answer (score 0):

So the stack trace says to place a symbolic breakpoint on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread.

I did that as was explained this question:
[A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988960/a-long-running-parse-operation-is-being-executed-on-the-main-thread)

Clicking through the results revealed a problem in the appDelegate with the local datastore.

I commented "Parse.enableLocalDatastore" out. 
After disabling the local datastore I can now log in.

(The local datastore was also giving me problems with pinning in another part of the app so I'm officially done using it.)